# Looking for directions in order to build an online web scraper database

Tags: python, database, web-scraping

I would like to start coding with python in order to build an online database. More specifically, I would like to run a site that scrapes data from other sites (who offer to share their content obviously) in order to centralize information.

I've dabbled in coding before and have a rudimentary understanding of programming languages, so I'm fine figuring out how to learn about variables, classes and the like. What I'm confused about is the conceptualization of it all and how to implement it. Maybe I can outline what I thought of individually and you guys can tell me whether that makes sense or not:

I thought of hosting a website which runs something like django and can thus execute python script or an app which gathers information from other sites, cuts out the important information and then displays it neatly and in order. This should also involve a database that is searchable. Now, is that something I need SQL for? Or any other database programming language? I never worked with databases before. I would also like to provide the option of suggestions, so that when you type in one term suggestions are being provided.

So, website code with HTML, CSS and JS, then a django framework running python and then...SQL? I hope that makes sense, at least that's what I'm considering right now.

I'd be glad to hear from you guys whether I'm thinking in the right terms here. Also, I'd be very happy if you could point me towards suitable resources. I searched a bit myself, stumbled across Automate The Boring Stuff and such, but so far that didn't really fit the scope of what I'm trying to do. Anyway, thanks in advance for any replies! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could subscribe to PythonWeekly. They have articles about scraping with python every once in a while.

See for example:
https://rrighart.github.io/Webscraping/